# Apache Ignite cache initialization with SQL DDL statements vs CacheConfiguration

Tags: ignite

Looking through the Apache Ignite 2.14.0 documentation, it's unclear if there is any material difference between creating a cache using SQL DDL statements (i.e., CREATE TABLE ...) vs. doing so programmatically with CacheConfiguration.

Do these ultimately result in the same underlying key-value store?  The one major difference appears to be that creating a CacheConfiguration using, say, a CacheJdbcPojoStoreFactory, it's possible to set it up as a read/write-through cache bound to an underlying RDBMS, which doesn't appear to be the case with the SQL DDL approach.

The reason I am asking is that I have found the Calcite Engine optimizer times out as the query becomes more complex.  I'm curious if there is a meaningful difference between how the caches are created and if this might change the behavior of the optimizer

The queries have been timing out in the Calcite optimization phase and I'm wondering if the way the caches are defined might impact this.   The caches are configured with QueryEntitys/QueryIndexes, etc. in way that would appear to mirror anything that would be doing using SQL DDL statements.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that they're the same. The more significant factor is that the Calcite-based SQL engine is currently in beta. You could open a ticket or raise the issue in the Ignite mailing list if you have a reproducer.